# How find info about eth0 device in snmp information?

Tags: python, snmp

How find info about eth0 device in  snmp information ?

Comment: More information please.  Maybe OS, language, what info you need, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access information via :

```
iso(1).org(3).dod(6).internet(1).mgmt(2).mib-2(1).interfaces(2).ifTable(2).ifEntry(1). ...
```

As you can see here under.

[image]

Here is a table view :

[image]

You'll find here a [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156853/what-is-the-best-snmp-implementation-for-python) about the best SNMP implementation for Python.